# Data not updating in react-bootstrap-table2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table2 for rendering the data into table.
say there are three fields in the table  "Quantity"  , "Cost Price" ,  "Total Price"
and the value of "Total Price" is ...Total Price= Cost Price * Total Price

so on the initial load , it all works fine but when i increment or decrement the "Quantity" value .......It does not reflects the change in the "Total Price". However "Quantity" value is updaing in the data , so react-bootstrap table is getting updated data but there is no change in the "Total Price" .........I have Delete feature also , its working fine , on clicking delete icon it deletes the product from the data and table gets updated according to data. 
But in case of Total Price it looks like its not updating the dom ..

Comment: You're gonna need to show some code here. Preferably a mini-demo in CodeSandbox or something.